# Android loadURL only loading half of html page

Tags: android, android-webview

**SOLVED: Problem was that the second picture was really large!**

I am a bit confused about this... probably I am missing something really basic.

I am trying to display this simple html page as part of my UI (there's lots of elements in there, not just the webview)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black">

    <div align="center">
    <h2>Blabla</h2>
    <p>
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="300" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="300" />
    </p>
    <h3>tralala</h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is how I try to display the content (the url is a real url, not an asset!):

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("url");
```

This is the relevant part of the main.xml file:

```
<WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

What happens is that it loads the first image plus the text blabla, but not the tralala and the second image. It's like it stops loading. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

image2.jpg was really huge and that seemed to cause the problem. Person responsible for html site now resized the picture and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check url is in the format as below

> "file:///android_asset/index.html"

if index.html is under asset folder.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't help :P I wrote "(the url is a real url, not an asset!" So well... But I figured out what the problem was... one of the pictures was enormous in size, now the person responsible for the html has changed that and it is working :)

Comment: you can answer your own question separately and accept as answer, otherwise it will be moved to Unanswered question.